# Prove $zw=0\iff z=0 \lor w=0$ for all complex numbers

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers

Question :

If $z$ and $w$ are complex numbers, then prove :

$$zw=0\iff z=0 \lor w=0$$

My proof :

$p\Rightarrow q$
Suppose $z\ne 0$

$\Rightarrow w=\left(z^{-1}z\right)\cdot w=z^{-1}\cdot (zw)=z^{-1}\cdot 0=0$

$p\Leftarrow q$
Suppose $z\ne 0\land w=0$

$\Rightarrow zw=z\cdot 0=0$

I'm not sure with my proof, cz this doesn't involve the facts that $z$ and $w$ have form ($a+bi$).

Comment: Why do you think you need to use the definition of complex numbers? This statement is actually true in any field. What you have to use is that every non zero complex number has an inverse with respect to multiplication.

Comment: $\Leftarrow$ is trivial, $\Rightarrow$ is correct, you can add the case $w\neq 0$, then you can show $z=0$ in the same way, hence $z=0\vee w=0$.

Comment: $\Bbb C$ is a field,  hence an integral domain, hence no divisors of zero.

Answer (score 1):

Per se, if you already know that the multiplication is associative, that $1\cdot w=w\cdot 1=w$ for all $w$ and that for all $z\ne 0$ there is some $z^{-1}$ such that $z^{-1}z=1$, then you can prove $[\Longrightarrow]$ using $[\Longleftarrow]$ and the aforementioned three formal properties.

I'd rather point out the following facts:

1. You are using the $[\Longleftarrow]$ part of the theorem in the proof of the $[\Longrightarrow]$ part, therefore the former should precede the latter.
2. I don't quite see why in your proof of $[\Longleftarrow]$ you start by assuming that exactly one of the two factors is $0$, since you need the proof to encompass the case when both are $0$ as well. Also, technically you are not proving the assertion, you are just taking it for granted.

Answer (score 1):

Let $zw=0$ and $z\neq0$.  Every nonzero complex number has an inverse.  Namely,  if $z=re^{i\theta}$, then $z^{-1}=1/re^{-i\theta}$. Now $w=z^{-1}zw=z^{-1}0=0$.